# Loading reflectively a CGO generated DLL

Tags: c, go, dll

Just trying to experiment with reflective DLL loading, so I wrote a simple messagebox:

```
package main
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
    "syscall"
)

//export OnProcessAttach
func OnProcessAttach() {
    const (
        NULL  = 0
        MB_OK = 0
    )
    caption := "Hola"
    title := "desdegoo"
    ret, _, _ := syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll").NewProc("MessageBoxW").Call(
        uintptr(NULL),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(caption))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(title))),
        uintptr(MB_OK))

    if ret != 1 {
        return
    }
    return
}

func main() {}
```

I generated a dll (just a messagebox with cgo/golang), using the following command
go build --buildmode=c-shared main.go

When loading the dll with LoadLibrary() and running the exported function OnProcessAttach it works (pops the message box), but when trying to achieve DLL reflective loading, by resolving the relocations and resolving the IAT it just don't work.
Seems like performing the base relocations and the IAT sets to null sections on .rdata that are used for initializing the go runtime (which initializes in the entrypoint from NT headers)
This is the piece of code I'm using for resolving the imports:

```
// resolve base relocations
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY relocations = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
    DWORD_PTR relocationTable = relocations.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)dllBase;
    DWORD relocationsProcessed = 0;


    while (relocationsProcessed < relocations.Size)
    {
        PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK relocationBlock = (PBASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)(relocationTable + relocationsProcessed);
        relocationsProcessed += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK);
        DWORD relocationsCount = (relocationBlock->BlockSize - sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_BLOCK)) / sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);
        PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY relocationEntries = (PBASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY)(relocationTable + relocationsProcessed);
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < relocationsCount; i++)
        {
            relocationsProcessed += sizeof(BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY);
            if (relocationEntries[i].Type == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }


            DWORD_PTR relocationRVA = relocationBlock->PageAddress + relocationEntries[i].Offset;
            DWORD_PTR addressToPatch = 0;
            ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)((DWORD_PTR)dllBase, relocationRVA), &addressToPatch, sizeof(DWORD_PTR), NULL);
            addressToPatch += deltaImageBase;
            memcpy((PVOID)((DWORD_PTR)dllBase + relocationRVA), &addressToPatch, sizeof(DWORD_PTR));
        }
    }
    
    // resolve IAT
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor = NULL;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY importsDirectory = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
    importDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(importsDirectory.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)dllBase);
    LPCSTR libraryName = "";
    HMODULE library = NULL;


    while (importDescriptor->Name != NULL)
    {
        libraryName = (LPCSTR)importDescriptor->Name + (DWORD_PTR)dllBase;
        library = LoadLibraryA(libraryName);
        if (library)
        {
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk = NULL;
            thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)dllBase + importDescriptor->FirstThunk);
            while (thunk->u1.AddressOfData != NULL)
            {
                if (IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(thunk->u1.Ordinal))
                {
                    LPCSTR functionOrdinal = (LPCSTR)IMAGE_ORDINAL(thunk->u1.Ordinal);
                    thunk->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)GetProcAddress(library, functionOrdinal);
                }
                else {
                    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)dllBase + thunk->u1.AddressOfData);
                    DWORD_PTR functionAddress = (DWORD_PTR)GetProcAddress(library, functionName->Name);
                    thunk->u1.Function = functionAddress;
                }
                ++thunk;
            }
        }
        importDescriptor++;
    }
```

After doing so I resolve the EAT looking for the OnProcessAttach function, running it directly doesn't work obviously because the go runtime isn't initialized, but trying to initialize it crashes the program because the above stated. It gives a EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION because tries to read a chunk of bytes that gets nullified.

Dissasembly of the entrypoint:
mov rax, qdword ptr ds:[address]
mov dword ptr ds:[rax]

Following the address in dump it looks null
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [..]

While the original dll has indeed values
90 2B C5 EA 01 [...]

I know I'm setting to null those bytes on .rdata, but can't figure out why that's happening when I perform the relocations, maybe the Go runtime doesn't fit for what I'm trying to do? Or is something else?

Comment: I suggest asking this on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/) instead: the question is likely to require multiple backs-and-forths, and is read by at least some of the core devs (while the `go` tag here on SO is watched by none of them, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After solving I just forgot posting the solution here
Error was in the following line

```
    ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPCVOID)((DWORD_PTR)dllBase, relocationRVA), &addressToPatch, sizeof(DWORD_PTR), NULL);
```

That was just a finger error, should be the add symbol and not the comma, that's why it was nullyfing the address.

Comment: Please also accept your own answer (that's OK on StackOverflow) ;-)